# bash extended glob - match files without prefix

Tags: bash, wildcards, bash-expansion

I'm trying to match filenames for a fail2ban jail - so I need to use filename globbing only - not regexes or bash scripting.

My `/var/log/apache2` directory contains files including:

```
example.com.error.log
db.example.com.error.log
app1.example.com.error.log
app2.example.com.error.log
```

I'm trying to create a glob to match all files ending in `.error.log` **except** `db.example.error.log` - is this possible?

I've tried `!(db)*.error.log` but this still matches `db.example.com.error.log`. I'm guessing the `!()` is matching no characters, allowing the `*` to match from the beginning of the filename.

Note: I don't want to have to extend the glob when new `appX` logfiles are added, so I can't use `@()` with the list of currently-known non-db filenames.

*(Background: I want to create a filter banning anyone requesting any phpMyAdmin URLs on any domain **except** db.example.com)*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The extended filename globbing pattern (supported by `bash` with the `extglob` shell option activated, and also by `ksh93`)

```
!(db*).error.log
```

will ignore anything that starts with `db`.

To be more specific:

```
!(db.example.com).error.log
```

This will ignore any name in the current directory that starts with exactly `db.example.com`.

The `!(db.example.com)` pattern acts like a "special `*`" that will not match the the string `db.example.com`.

---

Your pattern,

```
!(db)*.error.log
```

excludes any name that starts with `db`, but allows *any* string after that, which obviously includes `db`.

By the same analogy as above, `!(db)` acts "like `*`" but won't match the exact string `db`, leaving us with the pattern `**.error.log` *so to speak* (with the first `*` being "special").